# AVAudioPlayerDelegate doesn't call the method

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, audio-player

Here is the method inside a class:

```
import UIKIt
import Foundation

class notMoving {
    var drumPlayerObject = drumPlayer()
    var fileManagerObject = fileManager1()
    let drumStrength = 1
    var bassStrength = 1
    var synthStrength = 1
    var indexToPlay: Int = 0

    // here we start the drum player.
    func startToPlay()  {
        fileManagerObject.clearPlayedListDrum(drumStrength, KeyNoteOfInstDrum: "C")
        if let indexToPlay = fileManager1().randomizeTheNextInstrument(fileManager1().drums, Strength: drumStrength, KeyNote: "C")  {
            fileManager1().drums[indexToPlay].4 = true
            self.indexToPlay = indexToPlay
        }
        let instrument = fileManager1().drums[self.indexToPlay].0
        let name = fileManager1().drums[self.indexToPlay].1
        let length = fileManager1().drums[self.indexToPlay].2
        let power = fileManager1().drums[self.indexToPlay].3
        let ifplayed = fileManager1().drums[self.indexToPlay].4
        let tempo = Double(fileManager1().drums[self.indexToPlay].5)
        let bridge: Bool = false
        let extention = fileManagerObject.extentionOfFile
        let loops = fileManager1().drumNumberOfLoops()

        drumPlayerObject.play(instrument, name: name, extentionOfFile: extention, 
            length: length, power: power, ifplayed: ifplayed, tempo: tempo, loops: 
            loops, bridge: bridge)

        fileManager1().clearPlayedListDrum(drumStrength, KeyNoteOfInstDrum: "C")
    }
}
```

And here is AVAudioPlayerDelegate extension for a drumPlayer class.

```
extension drumPlayer : AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!, successfully flag: Bool) {
        println("finished playing \(flag)")
        var notMovingObject = notMoving()
        notMovingObject.startToPlay()
    }

    func audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur(player: AVAudioPlayer!, error: NSError!) {
        println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

But `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` doesn't call the `startToPlay` method after the file is finished.It just only prints "finished playing true"

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: Class names should start with a capital

Comment: Thank you HorseT! I will correct it) But do you have any ideas about the question?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by creating an instance `self.notMovingObject = NotMoving()` inside the "func play" of my player. So the instance is created only after the player starts.

Answer (score 1):

Your `notMovingObject` is not retained anywhere, thus after program exits `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying()` object is deallocated.

Comment: Ok. And what solution you could suggest?

Comment: Least invasive solution would probably be to add instance variable `notMovingObject` into `drumPlayer` class. However, I can't tell if its good solution as I don't have a bigger picture.

Comment: I've tried to add it, but it gives me Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5ddb7fe8) error and this in the output (lldb).