# `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

Having an issue where `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` isn't getting called...

I've looked at some other SO threads:

[Swift: AudioPlayerDidFinished will not be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707462/swift-audioplayerdidfinished-will-not-be-called)

[AVAudioPlayerDelegate doesn't call the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781684/avaudioplayerdelegate-doesnt-call-the-method)

...but still having the same issue.

I've set my `ViewController` to conform to `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
...
}
```

And create the player here; setting the delegate right after creating the player itself:

```
func startAudioEngine(audioFileURL: URL) {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.delegate = self

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is twofold:

1. `var player: AVAudioPlayer?` is declared local to `func startAudioEngine()`, so as soon as the function exists, you lose reference to `player`.
2. You are setting the delegate on the optionally bound `player`

Change to this (or something like this):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
  var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
  var player: AVAudioPlayer?
}
```

Then after you assign `player`, declare your delegate `self.player?.delegate = self`. Make sure to include `self.` so that the delegate is set on the class property and not the optional binding;